# Omission of subject in tensed clause

Tags: grammaticality, subjects, comparatives, subordinate-clauses, omissibility

I know the subject can be omitted in untensed clauses. But I've encountered with the following:

> You spent more money than was intended to be spent.

Here, 'than' seems to be functioning like a relative pronoun. Compare : *You spent the money that was intended.*
Could you please explain it with any authentic reference?

Comment: _Than_ is a word that occurs only in Comparative constructions; it identifies the baseline phenomenon being compared against. Comparatives are extremely complex constructions, involving at least two independent quantifications and a balancing of their values. They have their own grammar rules. In this case the baseline clause following _than_ should be something like _than the amount of money that `Indef` intended to spend_, with passive and various deletion rules producing this output.

Answer (score -1):

You are just being induced into wrong deductions on the count of the elliptical structure in this idiomatic comparison. A complete formulation would be

"You spent more money than  *the money that* was  intended to be spent.",

and so, "than" does not function as a relative pronoun; it might seem to be that way because a relative pronoun is elliptical.